# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, list, typeerror

I'm trying to sort a list of ints in python this is my code

```
for i in range (5):
     for j in range (6):
         list_dist.append(dist(i,j,pos_porte))
sorted_list=sorted (list_dist)
```

for some reason it doesn't work can you help?

Edit: dist is a function that returns distance:

```
def dist(a,s,b):
     distance=sqrt((pow(a-b[0],2)+pow(s-b[1],2)))
     print(distance)
```

Comment: Does `dist(...)` actually return ints? It looks like `list_dist` is full of `None`s

Comment: Please add some more details in your query.

Comment: dist is a function that returns distance

Comment: the list_dist.append i used it actually returns Nonetype elements is there any other function that adds elements to my list??

Comment: @Newbie the problem is not with `append`. The problem is with `dist` not returning anything. You have to add a `return` statement in `dist`

Answer (score 3):

Whatever the `dist` function is doing, it does not return anything. Hence `list_dist` contains `None`s and these can't be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `return` statement in your `dist` function. You can update it like:

```py
def dist(a,s,b):
     return sqrt((pow(a-b[0],2)+pow(s-b[1],2)))
```

Note that `print` does nothing more than printing whatever you input to stdout, it doesn't change the fact that your function is missing a `return` statement, thus returning always `None`